# Why does Python take forever to evaluate 1**4**4**4**4?

Tags: python, operators, exponentiation

I ran into a curious issue in both Python 2 and Python 3.

```
>>> 1**4**4**4
1L
which seems fine, but when I do this:
>>> 1**4**4**4**4
```

it swamps the CPU and never finishes.

Why?

I also ran these to see if it was something with the power function, or with the ** operator and it seems to be just the ** operator.

```
>>> (((((1**4)**4)**4)**4)**4)
1
>>> pow(pow(pow(pow(pow(pow(1,4),4),4),4),4),4)
1
>>> pow(pow(pow(pow(pow(pow(1.0,4),4),4),4),4),4)
1.0
>>> pow(pow(pow(pow(pow(pow(1L,4),4),4),4),4),4)
1L
>>> 1L**4**4**4
1L
```

I also tried another language and it seems to be just Python.

Why can't it evaluate this in microseconds? Can someone explain what it's doing with the CPU time?

Is there something non-intuitive about the order of operations that I am not understanding?

Comment: One other thing to note is that the peephole optimizer will pre-compute the rightmost `4**4` so really the comparison is between `1**4**256` and `1**4**4**256`.

Comment: Ah ok. I figured that was it. Thanks all.

Answer (score 6):

With the `**` operator, the binding rules are such that in unparenthesized expressions the *right-hand side is evaluated first*.

Your `1 ** 4 ** 4 ** 4 ** 4` is evaluated in the following order:

```
1 ** (4 ** (4 ** (4 ** 4)))
```

and it is producing and allocating the memory for the huge number on the right that takes all the time:

```
>>> 4 ** 4 ** 4
13407807929942597099574024998205846127479365820592393377723561443721764030073546976801874298166903427690031858186486050853753882811946569946433649006084096L
>>> 4 ** 4 ** 4 ** 4
# ... wait a long time as Python allocates GBs of memory ...
```

Quoting the [`**` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator):

> Thus, in an unparenthesized sequence of power and unary operators, the operators are evaluated from right to left

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, exponentiation is right associative, so

```
1**4**4**4**4
```

is not the same as

```
(((((1**4)**4)**4)**4)**4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it is not doing

```
(((((1**4)**4)**4)**4)**4)
```

It is doing

```
1**(4**(4**(4**(4**4))))
```

Note that the latter has to compute a HUGE number before simply raising 1 to that result.

Answer (score 0):

Right associativity:

```
>>> 2 ** 2 ** 3
256
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's slow because it has to evaluate `4**4**4**4`, which is does by multiplication to get the exact result.

(Don't forget that exponentiation is right-associative.)

P.S. `4**4**4` is `13407807929942597099574024998205846127479365820592393377723561443721764030073546976801874298166903427690031858186486050853753882811946569946433649006084096`, so computing `4**4**4**4` by multiplication is going to take a very, very long time.